# pushsubscription gives options instead of keys when using requestSubscription()

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/) to enable push notifications in my PWA. According to the tutorial, I should get a pushSubscription object like this:

```
{
  "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cbx2QC6AGbY:APA91bEjTzUxaBU7j-YN7ReiXV-MD-bmk2pGsp9ZVq4Jj0yuBOhFRrUS9pjz5FMnIvUenVqNpALTh5Hng7HRQpcUNQMFblTLTF7aw-yu1dGqhBOJ-U3IBfnw3hz9hq-TJ4K5f9fHLvjY",
  "expirationTime": null,
  "keys": {
    "p256dh": "BOXYnlKnMkzlMc6xlIjD8OmqVh-YqswZdut2M7zoAspl1UkFeQgSLYZ7eKqKcx6xMsGK7aAguQbcG9FMmlDrDIA=",
    "auth": "if-YFywyb4g-bFB1hO9WMw=="
  }
}
```

However when I inspect my subscription object I get something in the form of

```
{
  "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cbx2QC6AGbY:APA91bEjTzUxaBU7j-YN7ReiXV-MD-bmk2pGsp9ZVq4Jj0yuBOhFRrUS9pjz5FMnIvUenVqNpALTh5Hng7HRQpcUNQMFblTLTF7aw-yu1dGqhBOJ-U3IBfnw3hz9hq-TJ4K5f9fHLvjY",
  "expirationTime": null,
  "options": {
    "applicationServerKey": ArrayBuffer(65),
    "userVisibleOnly": true
  }
}
```

note that I do not get the keys object and instead get an options object.
Have the properties of the pushSubscription object changed? If I use this to send notifications, will it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving my pushSubscription object with Mongoose, I used `keys` instead of `options`
If I then inspect the object in my db (on MLab in my case) it looks like

```
{
  "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cbx2QC6AGbY:APA91bEjTzUxaBU7j-YN7ReiXV-MD-bmk2pGsp9ZVq4Jj0yuBOhFRrUS9pjz5FMnIvUenVqNpALTh5Hng7HRQpcUNQMFblTLTF7aw-yu1dGqhBOJ-U3IBfnw3hz9hq-TJ4K5f9fHLvjY",
  "expirationTime": null,
  "keys": {
    "p256dh": "BOXYnlKnMkzlMc6xlIjD8OmqVh-YqswZdut2M7zoAspl1UkFeQgSLYZ7eKqKcx6xMsGK7aAguQbcG9FMmlDrDIA=",
    "auth": "if-YFywyb4g-bFB1hO9WMw=="
  }
}
```

I guess that the object in my console is visualized differently, thus showing me the options parameter instead of keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subscription))
```

This will give you the keys.